# User Specified Index to Populate Image in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, keystonejs

I'm using handlebars with keystonejs. I have a lightbox where a user selects an image from a table. The image that the user selects from the table should then come up in the lightbox. Right now, I have it selecting the first image (statically). So in the lightbox I have:

```
<img src=uploads/{{data.residences.[0].floorplan.filename}}>
```

But I need to change that [0] to match whichever residence was selected. Seems like there's probably a straightforward answer but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This would involve some client-side JavaScript in order to determine what the images in the lightbox are, then switch between them. How are you currently displaying your images in the lightbox? Does it have functionality to switch between images natively, or did you make it yourself? Would you be able to post some CSS/JS code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using an ajax request to populate the lightbox with the image and all the data it needs so it is doing the processing client-side. It works perfectly fine but since I'm new to handlebars I thought maybe there was a way of doing it all within handlebars.

Comment: Handlebars is a server-side framework that has no interaction with your client. If the images are coming from your server, you could send them with `res.render` in order to pre-populate the lightbox image paths/`<img>` tags (or however the lightbox is implemented). The point is that Handlebars on its own should be able to put your images where they need to go in your HTML if you pass the image information to HBS.

Answer (score 0):

@willjfield Are you using the standard keystone generated template from the yeoman generator?  I wrote the HB implementation for it originally.  Believe I would need a little more context on the overall page, but like @shea mentioned you would need to most likely pass down an image map object {{residence.id}:{data.residences[i]}} <-- written as a pseudo es6 code using destructuring.  But you'd want to map the images to each individual residence so that way you could then create an image tag

```
<img src=uploads/{{imageStore[residence.id].floorplan.filename}}>
```